PJSIP registration process getting failed with status 503 (Connection refused) response on Push events
We are encountering an issue with PJSIP in our Android application. When the app is in a killed state and receives an FCM event related to a call, we initiate the PJSIP library initialisation followed by the SIP registration process. However, we are consistently receiving a 503 response most of the times even the server is Up and Running.
We have attempted various approaches to address this issue:

Initializing the library from both background and main threads.
First initialising the library, then starting the SIP registration process after a delay of 1 or 2 seconds.
Showing the call popup first after receiving the FCM event, then starting library initialisation.

Device have internet access during the registration process and my application using WebSocket as well and it is getting connected successfully.
Despite spending several days investigating, we have not been able to find a solution. Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
